# where do I set the web-service host name for an EJB3 client

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

Where do I set the web-service host name for an EJB3 client, when the web-service client is injected.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify any information. Please do. Before that, I'll assume you have `@WebServiceClient` annotation. It has a `wsdlLocation` property which can be set to a full `URL`, including the host name of the provider.

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like how JMS clients work, then you would need to provide the client with a JNDI that refers to the address of the service provider.